# Cannot train LUIS app

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Recently, I am unable to train my LUIS app. When I hit Train, I get the message 'Queued for training.'.
After about 5mins, this changes to the following error: 'Training failed: A server error occurred. Please refresh the page and try again.'
Refreshing or logging in again doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Pieter

Update: I found a few comments that suggests to just try again later (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/117c0a6a-b5d9-4d81-8263-7df47f903828/luis-cannot-publish-or-train-the-app?forum=LUIS).
This doesn't work for me as I have been unable to train this app for more than a week now.
I have also logged a ticket through luis.ai support. No feedback as of yet.

Comment: Seems likely there's a log file somewhere with some useful info for you.

Comment: Hi ceejayoz, I couldn't find any log files accessible through the LUIS portal.  Appreciated if you could point me in the right direction. I also tried exporting this LUIS app and then created a new app by importing its JSON. This new app is able to train successfully.

Comment: Hi Pieter are you still running into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested now and this seems to have resolved itself as it trained successfully for the first time in about a week. As such I'm marking this question as answered.